# Migrate backlog items from ScrumWise to Visual Studio Online?

Tags: import, azure-devops, backlog, scrumboard

Our project currently is using [Scrumwise](https://www.scrumwise.com) for our agile project planning and we want to migrate to either JIRA or Visual Studio Online.

Is it possible to migrate backlog items (`xml/csv/excel` format) into VSO? Does it require a plugin tool or utility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Excel can help you add work items into a team project in VSO.

- install Microsoft Excel 2007 or a more recent version.
- install visual studio to get the Team Foundation add-in to Excel
- in Excel, start with a blank worksheet, find **Team** ribbon and click **New List** to connect to your team project hosted in Visual Studio Online, then select **Input list**
- specify the titles of the work items you want to add and their work item type.
- publish your worksheet

Detailed information, you can refer to the MSDN documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel

Comment: In order to have 'Team' tab in Excel, you need to download and install Team Explorer. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40776